# How to get the archive reason based on the archive_reason

Tags: mysql

I need to write a query but am a newbie to writing querys that involve 2 tables.

The first table 'clients' has the following columns "id, archive_reason, name, phone". The second table, 'archive' has the following columns "id, archive_reason".

What I need to do is get the archive reason based on the archive_reason in the clients table if that makes sense... and then return * from the clients table, including the archive reason from the arhive table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT clients.*, archive.archive_reason FROM clients, archive WHERE clients.id=archive.id;
```

Is that what you were asking for?

This is called a JOIN, and there are many more (and better) ways to do it:

http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp

http://www.databasedev.co.uk/query_joins.html

Comment: This is what i have so far - SELECT * FROM clients WHERE archive = 1 .... What i need to add to this is 'get archive_reason from archive where id = clients.archive_reason .... I hope this makes more sense to what im looking for

Comment: You have no field named archive, only a table... so what you are asking isn't really clear.  Can you tell us the bigger picture of what you are trying to accomplish so we can give better advice?  Specifically, it would be good to know what is in these tables.

Comment: Sorry ... These querys really make my head swim .... Ok .. the 2 tables 'clients' and 'archive' .... in the clients table i have id, archive_reason, name, phone ... in the archive table i have the following id, archive_reason ... The archive.archive_reason is what i need to get from the archive table, the relationship between the 2 tables is clients.archive_reason and archive.id ... when it finds the one that matches, it returns the archive.archive_reason and all of the data from the cleints table ... im sorry if its confusing

Comment: I guess, I don't understand what archive_reason is in either table.  Is this text?  An ID pointing to a corresponding table?  Are you saying that both tables contain the exact same id's and archive_reasons?